# Processing .txt Input as Cartesian Coordinates

Tags: objective-c, c

Exercise: 
Using Obj C and C, create a command line app that will: 
• take a txt file with Cartesian Coordinates in following format:

```
(2;9)
(5;6)
...
```

•(other technical requirements)

Question: what would be the best way to process out an input data? 
C has functions such as `fscanf` `fgetc` and `fgets`. 
If I understood correctly - we can't use `fgets` -  because it is for characters not for integers/floats/doubles. And it will read every character. 
And we cant use `fgetc` - because it returns only 1 character (the next one in the stream) that is converted to an int.

I had a several approaches, but non of them worked so far. 
First - to use a `for` loop. I wanted to count number of coordinate pairs first, then sort out data from .txt file into 2 arrays for x and y coordinates.:

```
float xCoordinate [MAXSIZE] = {0.0};
float yCoordinate [MAXSIZE] = {0.0};

float x;
float y;
FILE *handle;
handle = fopen ("points.txt", "r");
int ch;
int n;

ch=fgetc(handle)!=EOF; //error. This will read every character including ( ) and ; . 
//Maybe I omit this loop condition? 

for (n=0; n<=ch ; (fscanf(handle, "(%f;%f)", &x, &y) )
{
xCoordinate [n+1] = x;
yCoordinate [n+1] = y;
}
```

Comment: The expression `ch=fgetc(handle)!=EOF` will assign the result of `fgetc(handle)!=EOF` to `ch`, which means that `ch` will be either `0` or `1`. Unless the file failed open, because then `handle` will be `NULL` and you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Are you allowed to use NSFileHandle?

Comment: yes, the `fgetc` function doesn't belong to here. About the NSFileHandle - I can use anything. Googling about it now.

Comment: Your description of the file does not indicate a first line that contains the number of following lines.  Does the first line of the file actually contain a count of the number of following lines?

Comment: always check (!=NULL) the returned value from fopen() to assure the operation was successful

Comment: in the posted code, it does not matter about a line count.  fscanf() will fail to read two floats when it tries to read past the end of the file.

Comment: for readability, always indent your code.  Do not use tabs.  suggest using 4 spaces to offset each indentation level

Comment: @user3629249 1. no, in the .txt file we don't know how many coordinate pairs (future polygon vertexes) will be there.  2. Omitted the NULL test for SO only. 3. didn't understand why `fscanf` will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone answered this question and then deleted it. 
Luckily, I saved his code. 
The best part - it works:

```
    float xCoordinate [MAXSIZE] = {0.0};
    float yCoordinate [MAXSIZE] = {0.0};

    float x;
    float y;
    FILE *handle;
    int n = 0;

    if ( ( handle = fopen ("points.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf ("could not open file\n");
        return 1; // or exit(1);
    }
    while ( ( fscanf(handle, " (%f;%f)", &x, &y) ) == 2)
    {
        xCoordinate[n] = x;
        yCoordinate[n] = y;
        n++;
        if ( n >= MAXSIZE)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose ( handle);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should read the file as long as the fscanf returns two items successfully read and n is less than MAXSIZE.

```
float xCoordinate [MAXSIZE] = {0.0};
float yCoordinate [MAXSIZE] = {0.0};

float x;
float y;
FILE *handle;
int n = 0;

if ( ( handle = fopen ("points.txt", "r")) == NULL) 
{
    printf ("could not open file\n");
    return 1; // or exit(1);
}
while ( ( fscanf(handle, " (%f;%f)", &x, &y) ) == 2)
{
    xCoordinate[n] = x;
    yCoordinate[n] = y;
    n++;
    if ( n >= MAXSIZE)
    {
        break;
    }
}

fclose ( handle);
```